# Arranging identical balls in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, circles

In how many ways can 4 identical red balls and two identical white balls be arranged in a circle? This is an elementary problem, but many tries have not yet yielded results. I tried by taking the total arrangements as (n-1)! because it is a circle but then the answer is fractional. Could someone explain how I might go about with it?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can consider them in linear arrangement. Therefore $\frac{6!}{4!2!}=15$ arrangements.

Comment: @AvZ They are in a circle, not a line.

Comment: I tell you, Nothing can stop me today from leaving stupid comments over every question. I need to sleep.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are over-thinking it. Since the balls are identical, there are only $3$ arrangements:
$$
\dots WWRRRR \dots\quad
\dots WRWRRR \dots\quad
\dots WRRWRR \dots
$$
where $\dots$ means that the circle wraps around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if there were a greater number of identical objects to arrange in a circle? Would there be a way you could deduce the number of arrangements by dividing (n-1)!, since it is a circle, by the number of each object, or something similar?

Comment: I'm not strong enough in combinatorics to answer this. You should post this as a separate question. Be sure to link back this question for reference. Also, when you say "greater number of identical objects" do you mean something like (4 White and 7 Red) or (2 White, 2 Red, and 4 Blue)?

Comment: Yeah. Something like 4 white and 7 red.

Comment: @SR1: If you post a new question about $m$ white and $n$ red balls in a circle and ping me, I'll answer it. Basically there are two approaches, one by the inclusion-exclusion principle and the other by the orbit-counting theorem. The first is conceptually simpler but requires more computation while the second involves group theory but requires much less computation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, @mapierce271 is right.

Let us assume that the first ball is white. (First ball we look at, since a circle has no 'first' point).

I would start by seeing the number of balls between the 2 white balls:
a) 0 - Yes, it is possible. WWRRRR
b) 1 - This, too, can be done. WRWRRR
c) 2 - Again. WRRWRR
d) 3 - This would lead to WRRRWR, which is a cycled arrangement of b)
e) 4 - This would be WRRRRW, which is another way of writing a)

So, only a), b) and c) are unique and correct.

The question is easy since there are only 2 white balls. It gets complicated with more than 3.